# Why can't I find the default Magento theme being loaded?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

Should be pretty simple.  I am trying to find what theme is being loaded in Magento to create my own custom theme. The problem is the mine (ver. 1.7.0.2) has no files in the frontend->default->default folder so I can't put any print statements there or see which template Magento is loading to learn more about it.  Print statements in base->default don't seem to work either.

And where is the home page template located?

I don't know why Magento makes this so hard or maybe I'm just looking at old info that's not applicable anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Turn on template path hints](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/template-path-hints-tutorial-video/).  Also disable the cache from **System > Cache Management** while you are doing any theme work.

Comment: LifeSAVER!!! It seems all the calls are made via calls to links...Is there something like an index.php file that makes those calls to get the blocks and links etc? If so where is it located?

Comment: Themes are _way_ more complicated than that, a lot of it is done with XML files.  See RThomas' answer for the designer's guide.  Also, the home page is partly a CMS page which you can edit directly from the admin.

Comment: To answer that question, you need to understand the Magento process flow.  Magento uses index.php in the root for all requests, and calls Mage::run, which goes into Mage_Core_Model_App::run, which builds all the require needs and dispatchs the frontend controller.  If you need to get a list of all templates, PHP, js, you should look at investing into Alan Storm's Commerce Bug, which will help you on top of any browser dev tools that you are already using.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for other answer suggesting you turn on template path hints.  That is a great way to figure out the structure of how things work in Magento.

I would also recommend the user guide.  It's been updated to apply to 1.7.  You used to have to pay for the guide but they make it available for free now.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/magento-user-guide

As well as the latest designers guide that has info specific for templates etc.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide